# Subtracting shapes [Photoshop CS6]

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to subtract a rectangle from a triangle. While the process does seem to complete successfully, the result is not exactly what I expected. I know other users have had similar issues but I couldn't find any that corresponds to my problem. From the image, I need to be able to select only the remaining trapezoid, but If I try to, The whole triangle gets selected. 
[image]
To help you resolve my issue, I will write the exact steps I took:

- Create a polygon using polygon tool [Properties set to 'Shape' and 'New layer']
- Select rectangle tool [Properties set to 'Shape' and 'Subtract Front Shape']
- Create the rectangle
- Use Direct Selection Tool to select the remaining trapezoid

I am relatively new to Photoshop, so I apologize in advance for making any beginner mistakes or not understanding how specific tools work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would draw the rectangle from the opposite site, so as to form your trapezoid through intersection. Just use the Intersect Shape Areas (see screengrab), and once you're happy with the shape, press Merge Shape Components to get your finalised path.

[image]

Comment: Excellent!!! Exactly what I need. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem at all. :)